# Overlap div over html5 video player issue in UC browser

Tags: css, html, uc-browser

Is that possible to overlap div element over HTML5 video player in UC browser.

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="goover"></div>
  <video width="400" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">`
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70vv3uy8/)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question more?

Comment: Could you try moving the `div.goover` after `video` and then set `video`'s `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1`

Comment: I tried it in both mobile uc and pc uc, it worked well. Which edition of uc browser are you using?

Comment: I believe this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062990/video-refuse-to-obey-css-rule-in-mobile-ucbrowser and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720720/video-plays-over-top-of-menu-on-uc-mobile-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1 which have yet to be answered. If you were able to find a solution for overlaying content above playing video on UC please let us know @Carlos, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I assume here you want your div to be the same size as your video. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858472/make-a-divs-size-and-position-the-same-as-a-videos) has a pretty nice answer for you.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var width = $("#vid").width();
  var height = $("#vid").height();
  $(".goover").css({
    'width': width,
    'height': height
  });
}, 10);
```

```css
.test{
   position:relative
 }

.goover{
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="goover"></div>
  <video width="400" id="vid" controls autoplay>         
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>
```

I modified the snippet a little bit to match yours better. And I also put a little of transparency in the red background so you can see that the div is overlapping over the video.

**EDIT :**

Tested on UC-Browser V6.1.2015.1007 (latest release for now) and it works just fine.

**EDIT2 :**

The controls weren't hidden in UC-Browser, fixed it in css by adding the z-index.

**EDIT3 :**

I've added the autoplay attribute on the video tag to see it working while in play mode.

Comment: Is this working fine when video is in play mode? because UC browser replace video player with their player that has highest priority

Comment: Yes it works, I've added the autoplay attribute and tested it in UC-Browser

Comment: It is not working on mobile UC browser. I should have mention it but anyways thanks for you valuable effort

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
https://jsfiddle.net/zpjsz8g8/1/

```
.test { position: relative }
.goover {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff0000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*right:0px*/
    width: 400 px;
    z - index: 1;
}
```

or

```
var videoContainer = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
var goover = document.getElementsByClassName('goover')[0];

goover.style.height = videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
goover.style.width = videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px'
```