# Video refuse to obey CSS rule in mobile UCBrowser

Tags: html, css, video

My video element overlaps all elements in my mobile UCBrowser so I try to add some CSS styling to make it work fine

```
video {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width:100%;
}
```

I also added this elements but the video overlaps them

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    z-index:1000;
}

.element {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    z-index:900;
}
```

Please how do I make the `header` and `.element` overlap the video

Comment: Did you try wrapping the `video` tag inside a `div` and then apply negative `z-index` to that container div? Don't know if this will work?

Comment: No... It didn't work

Comment: Can you add some html

Comment: @doggiebrezy Were you able to find an answer to this problem? I am running into the same. Is there a bug reported on UC browser's rendering engine for this? Thanks.