# Video plays over top of menu on UC Mobile Browser

Tags: html, css

This question is basically a copy of [Video refuse to obey CSS rule in mobile UCBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062990/video-refuse-to-obey-css-rule-in-mobile-ucbrowser)

I tried to resurrect that question but I couldn't comment on it because of lack of rep but it is essentially the same issue.

We have a video playing on our page.  When it is played in the UC Mobile Browser (I think it uses its own player?)  On the same page we have a menu that opens up.  The problem is that when we open up the menu the video is playing over it.  No matter what z-index we give the menu it always plays underneath the video.  There seems to be woefully little documentation online about the UC Mobile Browser.

Not sure how important the css is...because the issue seems pretty straight forward but here it is.

Menu css:

```
.block-nav-menu {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 1031;
background: #fff;
width: 270px;
-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
-ms-transform: translateX(100%);
transform: translateX(100%);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s;
transition: transform 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
height: 100%;
background: url(../../../images/mobile/bg.jpg);}
```

Video player css:

```
.video-holder {
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
background: #000;}

.video-holder video {
display: block;
width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
z-index: -1;}
```

Comment: You should specify z-index for `.video-holder` wrapper instead of `video` element i think. Try giving `z-index:100` for `.video-holder` and `z-index:10000` for `.block-nav-menu`.

Comment: Didn't change anything.  I think it is because the UC Browser pops up a separate video window on top of everything.

Comment: @ Michael Gurney, am experiencing the same exact problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope.  No solution as of yet.  Was hoping someone here could give some insight but no luck as of yet.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution @MichaelGurney? I am also running into this issue. Is there a formal bug reported on UC rendering engine? Thanks.